# Фильтр данных из обьекта Vuex на Frontend

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Хочу реализовать такую схему. Из Vuex мне прилетает массив persons обьектами:

`[{name: 'lera', balance: 200,},{name: 'tyma', balance: 400,},{name: 'vlad', balance: 100,}]`

Потом я вывожу его через v-for на страницу. Также добавляю кнопки фильтрации по полю `balance`
И вот в чем вопрос. Я пытаюсь реализовать фильтр через methods:

```
filter() {
    const balanceFilter = this.$store.state.persons.filter(person => person.balance > 240)
    this.$store.state.persons = balanceFilter
}
```

И вешаю то на кнопку.
Но при нажатии ничего не происходит. Кто нибудь знает ответ на этот вопрос? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того допускаете ли вы изменение исходного массива данных, можно пойти разными путями:

Допустим, полагаясь на исходные данные из `vuex` вы создаете в компоненте фильтр и отфильтрованные данные храните в нем же, без модификации исходных данных во `vuex`.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    persons: [{
      name: 'lera',
      balance: 200,
    }, {
      name: 'tyma',
      balance: 400,
    }, {
      name: 'vlad',
      balance: 100,
    }]
  },
  getters: {
    getPersons: (state) => {
      return state.persons
    }
  },
})

const {
  mapGetters
} = Vuex

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {
    newPersons: []
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getPersons'])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.newPersons = this.$store.state.persons
  },
  methods: {
    filterPersons() {
      const balanceFilter = this.$store.state.persons.filter(person => person.balance > 240)
      this.newPersons = balanceFilter
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in newPersons">{{ item.name }} ({{item.balance}})</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="filterPersons">filter balance > 240</button>
</div>
```

В случае если вы хотите получить доступ к отфильтрованным данным глобально из других компонентов, можете провести модификацию вашего исходного массива данных. Это не всегда практично, но пример приведу, как это сделать (обращаю внимание, что проводить модификацию хранилища `vuex` нужно только используя [мутации](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/mutations.html)):

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    persons: [{
      name: 'lera',
      balance: 200,
    }, {
      name: 'tyma',
      balance: 400,
    }, {
      name: 'vlad',
      balance: 100,
    }]
  },
  getters: {
    getPersons: (state) => {
      return state.persons
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPersons: (state, data) => {
      state.persons = data
    }
  },
})

const {
  mapGetters,
  mapMutations
} = Vuex

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getPersons'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['setPersons']),
    filterPersons() {
      const balanceFilter = this.getPersons.filter(person => person.balance > 240)
      this.setPersons(balanceFilter)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in getPersons">{{ item.name }} ({{item.balance}})</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="filterPersons">filter balance > 240</button>
</div>
```

И чтобы не потерять исходные данные (перезаписать новыми данными в результате фильтрации) можете создать в `vuex` свойство, допустим, `filteredPersons` и в нее записывать текущие отфильтрованные данные, чтобы получить доступ к этим данным из любого компонента вашего приложения.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    persons: [{
      name: 'lera',
      balance: 200,
    }, {
      name: 'tyma',
      balance: 400,
    }, {
      name: 'vlad',
      balance: 100,
    }],
    filteredPersons: []
  },
  getters: {
    getPersons: (state) => {
      return state.persons
    },
    getFilteredPersons: (state) => {
      return state.filteredPersons
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setFilteredPersons: (state, data) => {
      state.filteredPersons = data
    }
  },
})

const {
  mapGetters,
  mapMutations
} = Vuex

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getPersons', 'getFilteredPersons'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['setFilteredPersons']),
    filterPersons(balance) {
      const balanceFilter = this.getPersons.filter(person => person.balance > balance)
      this.setFilteredPersons(balanceFilter)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h4>Исходные данные (Vuex)</h4>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in getPersons">{{ item.name }} ({{item.balance}})</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Отфильтрованные (Vuex)</h4>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in getFilteredPersons">{{ item.name }} ({{item.balance}})</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="filterPersons(199)">filter balance > 199</button>
  <button @click="filterPersons(240)">filter balance > 240</button>
</div>
```

Это не которые из возможных вариантов и они не являются эталонными в решении вашей задачи.